# How to insert fixed data into database after NHibernate db created?

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want to insert fixed data into tables(like Cities, Towns, Jobs, Departments etc.) after database created. I think I need a NHibernate helper class to do this but how?

```
public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    IPersistenceConfigurer dbConfigurer = MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("test_nh"));

    var fConfig = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(dbConfigurer)
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
            .AddFromAssemblyOf<Adres>()
            )
        .ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
                                {
                                    SchemaExport config = new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true);
// I think code will be here
// There is file which contains sql script to insert data
                                })
        .BuildSessionFactory();

    return fConfig;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After creation of db, I didn't know how to handle session. I figured out now and solution is like this:

```
public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    IPersistenceConfigurer dbConfigurer = MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("test_nh"));

    var fConfig = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(dbConfigurer)
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
            .AddFromAssemblyOf<Adres>()
            )
        .ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
                                {
                                    SchemaExport config = new SchemaExport(cfg);
                                    config.Create(true, true);

                                    var ses1 = cfg.BuildSessionFactory().OpenSession();
                                    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"P:\cbo\App_Code\FixedSQL\Countries.sql");
                                    string sql = tr.ReadToEnd();
                                    var ulkeler= ses1.CreateSQLQuery(sql).List();
                                })
        .BuildSessionFactory();
    return fConfig;
}
```

PS: sql file size important for MySQL. If you want to extend it you should add this line into `my.ini` file:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 32M
```